# Copying Y scale value onto multiple objects

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, scripting, interface

The thickness (Y-axis) are all different value and I have been attempting to reset them all the a particular value without doing it one by one. I also tried using the copy attributes plugin but it only offers to copy all the scale values instead of just the ones for the Y value. **Any thoughts how I can copy Y scale to multiple objects?**
[image]

Comment: If anyone is offering a script can I please also be told how to install that, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a script (I don't know if there is another option) for now

- copy and paste the script in the blender text editor
- select the objects
- the object with the right scale should the active object (yellow outline , others red )
- in the text editor click Run Script

---

```
import bpy

s= bpy.context.object.scale[1]
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    obj.scale[1] = s
```

Comment: IF your bothered BUT not important, could you make a script that sets the origin to geometry for multiple objects as well :3. Its not needed but good to make my scene look clean with the dots yet again not needed so don't bother if its too much of a hassle already got the main prob fixed ty.

Comment: @TheEdge63 I was away at the time, but i have added it now

Comment: @TheEdge63 Origin to geometry already works on multiple objects by default..